# How do we get the number of prime divisors?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

We have a natural square-free number $n$ such that $2^5\cdot 3^6\cdot 5^4\equiv 0 \pmod {\tau(n)}$.

Which is the maximum number of different primes that can divide $n$ ?

$$$$

We have that $\tau(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$. So we have that $\tau (n) = \alpha\cdot 2^5\cdot 3^6\cdot 5^4$.

But how does this gives us the number of prime divisors?

Comment: Hint: if $n$ is square-free and has $k$ prime divisors, then $\tau(n)=2^k$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: "So we have that  $\tau (n) = \alpha\cdot 2^5\cdot 3^6\cdot 5^4$".  I think you have that backwards.  You should have $2^5\cdot 3^6\cdot 5^4 = \tau(n)\cdot \alpha$ for some integer $\alpha$.  .... Now take TonyK's hint....

Comment: Do you mean that we have $\alpha=2^i\cdot 3^5\cdot 5^4$ and so $\tau (n)=2^k$ where $k$ is at most $5$ ? @TonyK

Comment: Well if you take my correction then  $2^53^65^4 = \tau(n)\alpha$ so $\frac {2^53^65^4}{\tau(n)}=\alpha\in \mathbb Z$.  And if you take TonyK's hint that $\tau(n)=2^k$ we have $2^k|2^53^65^4$ and by Euclid's lemma that would mean and $2^k|2^5$ which means.... $k \le 5$.

Comment: I see! Thank you! :-) @fleablood

Comment: $\tau(n)$ divides $2^5\cdot 3^6 \cdot 5^4$, then $\tau(n)=2^i 3^j 5^k$ where $i\leq 5$, $j\leq 6$, $k\leq 4$. $\tau=\alpha 2^5 3^6 5^4$ is not correct.

Comment: If the prime factorization of $n$ is $$n = \prod_{i=1}^r ~\left[p_i^{a_i}\right],$$ then $$\tau(n) = \prod_{i=1}^r \left(a_i + 1\right).$$  You also have that $\tau(n)$ is a divisor of $\displaystyle \left[2^5 \times 3^6 \times 5^4\right].$  So, the question is, what is the maximum value for $~r~$ ?

Comment: Use the visualization of my last comment.  The value of $~r~$ is maximized by requiring that each factor $(a_i + 1)$ be a prime number, rather than a composite number.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)